# HTML Jquery radio buttons switch as per select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons that switch on selected. When one of the two radio buttons is selected, there should be a description for it, when the other is selected, the description should change.

The code below does pretty much what I want, but the problem is it does it on CLICK. One of the radio buttons will come as pre-selected (with 'checked' attribute) and a description isn't going to show up until the user clicks a radio button. Thus I would like for the description to match the corresponding radio button if one of them is pre-checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="subscription-type"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".subscription-desc").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.subscription-desc {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbar-3">
    <input type="radio" id="classic" name="subscription-type" value="classic" class="choose" checked>
    <label for="classic">Classic</label>
    <input type="radio" id="adventurer" name="subscription-type" value="adventurer" class="choose">
    <label for="adventurer">Adventurer</label>
</div>
<div class="classic subscription-desc">
    Description 1
</div>
<div class="adventurer subscription-desc">
    Description 2
</div>
```

Basically in the above, "Classic" option will come as pre-selected, but there is no description for it until the user clicks it.

Seems like a simple problem but I just can't find a solution for it. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the `.click` event on the `:checked` radio button so that it fires the click event:

```
$('input[name="subscription-type"]:checked').click();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="subscription-type"]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".subscription-desc").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });

  $('input[name="subscription-type"]:checked').click();
});
```

```css
.subscription-desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbar-3">
  <input type="radio" id="classic" name="subscription-type" value="classic" class="choose" checked>
  <label for="classic">Classic</label>
  <input type="radio" id="adventurer" name="subscription-type" value="adventurer" class="choose">
  <label for="adventurer">Adventurer</label>
</div>
<div class="classic subscription-desc">
  Description 1
</div>
<div class="adventurer subscription-desc">
  Description 2
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can extract the code that does the display into a function and call that:

```
function updateSubscription() {
  var inp = $('input[name="subscription-type"]:checked');
  var inputValue = $(inp).attr("value");
  var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
  $(".subscription-desc").not(targetBox).hide();
  $(targetBox).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="subscription-type"]').click(updateSubscription);
  updateSubscription();
});
```

```js
function updateSubscription() {
  var inp = $('input[name="subscription-type"]:checked');
  var inputValue = $(inp).attr("value");
  var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
  $(".subscription-desc").not(targetBox).hide();
  $(targetBox).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="subscription-type"]').click(updateSubscription);
  updateSubscription();
});
```

```css
.subscription-desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbar-3">
  <input type="radio" id="classic" name="subscription-type" value="classic" class="choose" checked>
  <label for="classic">Classic</label>
  <input type="radio" id="adventurer" name="subscription-type" value="adventurer" class="choose">
  <label for="adventurer">Adventurer</label>
</div>
<div class="classic subscription-desc">
  Description 1
</div>
<div class="adventurer subscription-desc">
  Description 2
</div>
```

Note you can also use

```
 var inputValue = $('input[name="subscription-type"]').val()
```

instead of

```
var inp = $('input[name="subscription-type"]:checked');
var inputValue = $(inp).attr("value");
```

I've kept the code above close to your original, just replacing the clicked `this` with `$('input[name="subscription-type"]:checked')`

Another alternative is to show the correct description at the time of load - this way you also don't get the "FOUC" (flash of unstyled content) where the description is displayed only after the page has fully loaded.

How you do this will depend on how you set the 'checked' value on the radio at page load, so may not be a suitable solution.